# Unwanted association when associating contact to company

Tags: hubspot-api

My problem is that i get unwanted association when associating contact to company. As it can be seen below i create associations for two contacts to same customer, but the result is that they both get two type of association, eventhough I only have specified one.

I am posting following json on {{baseUrl}}/crm/v4/associations/contacts/companies/batch/create

```
{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "from": "11751",
            "to": "9314823150",
            "types": [
                {    
                    "associationCategory": "HUBSPOT_DEFINED",
                    "associationTypeId": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "from": "11752",
            "to": "9314823150",
            "types": [
                {
                    "associationCategory": "HUBSPOT_DEFINED",
                    "associationTypeId": "279"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

"associationTypeId": "1" is company_to_contact
"associationTypeId": "279" is company_to_contact_unlabeled

when I get the company on {{baseUrl}}/crm/v3/objects/companies/9314823150?associations=contacts is there assosiations not specified in my create association request;

```
{
    "id": "9314823150",
    "properties": {
        "createdate": "2023-12-18T15:53:21.146Z",
        "domain": null,
        "hs_lastmodifieddate": "2024-01-03T08:04:04.525Z",
        "hs_object_id": "9314823150",
        "name": "KBJ Miljø ApS"
    },
    "createdAt": "2023-12-18T15:53:21.146Z",
    "updatedAt": "2024-01-03T08:04:04.525Z",
    "archived": false,
    "associations": {
        "contacts": {
            "results": [
                {
                    "id": "11751",
                    "type": "company_to_contact"
                },
                {
                    "id": "11752",
                    "type": "company_to_contact"
                },
                {
                    "id": "11751",
                    "type": "company_to_contact_unlabeled"
                },
                {
                    "id": "11752",
                    "type": "company_to_contact_unlabeled"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How to avoid the association not specified in the create association request?

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem is now. When creating firsts association for contact to company will the association always be the contacts primary connection to a company. By bad was that is saw the association as the company primary contact and not as the contacts primary association to a company.